# How to copy structure inside the function in C? memcpy

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, memcpy

I'm student, so sorry for a stupid question if it's actually is. Didn't finish C lang module yet :c

So the `memcpy();` in *core.c* file doesn't work like it should. Or maybe it just works in the way I don't need. The question is help to find a solution for the following task:

The idea is to have a function `multiply();` which accepts **nMatrix** [4x4] and **nVector** [4] pointers. It suppose to make buffer(tempVector) for getting multiplied results and then `memcpy` the whole structure to **nVector**.

But instead beautiful multiplied vector result it gives garbage from the memory.
Also before go out of the scope I free the **tempVector** array to prevent any bad heap memory management. Unfortunately the **nVector** array is still depends on copied memory from **tempVector**.

I would appreciate any advice! :D

So that is the problem code part - 
*core.c*

```
#include "core.h"
#include "init.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#define vecLength 4

typedef struct Vector {
double * vector;
int N;
} Vector;

typedef struct Matrix {
double ** matrix;
int nRow;
int nCol;
} Matrix;
...
...
void multiply(Vector* nVector, Matrix* nMatrix)
    {
    Vector tempVector;
    vectorInit(&tempVector);
    for(int i = 0; i < nMatrix->nRow; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < nMatrix->nCol; j++)
            tempVector.vector[i]+= nMatrix->matrix[i][j]*nVector->vector[j];

    memcpy(nVector,&tempVector,sizeof(Vector));
    vectorFree(&tempVector);
    }
```

*main.c*

```
int main(){
    ...
    ...
    Vector* v_Test;
    Matrix* m_Test;

    //Test structures memory allocation
    v_Test = (Vector*) malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    m_Test = (Matrix*) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

    //Initialization of vector in structure
    vectorInit(v_Test);

    for(int i = 0; i < v_Test->N; i++)
        v_Test->vector[i]=i+1;

    //Print vector
    vectorPrint(v_Test);
    getch();

    //Initialization of matrix in structure
    matrixInit(m_Test);

    for(int i=0; i<m_Test->nCol; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<m_Test->nCol;j++)
            m_Test->matrix[i][j]=m_Test->nRow*i+j;


    //Print matrix
    matrixPrint(m_Test);
    getch();


    multiply(v_Test,m_Test);

    vectorPrint(v_Test);
    getch();


    vectorFree(v_Test);
    getch();

    matrixFree(m_Test);
    getch();
  }
...
...
}
```

Comment: If you solve your problem, post an Answer and accept it. Don't edit the solution into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Already found the solution by trying the last idea before upload. So when you call `memcpy` it just copies array pointer of the vector which will be deallocated in the next instruction `vectorFree();`. So to prevent that we just copy the actual array from **tempVector** to **nVector** structure!*

*Solution in code:*

> memcpy(nVector->vector,tempVector.vector,vecLength*sizeof(double));

*I still upload it cause I paid 45 min to write this question. And I hope it will help anyone in the future :)*

*Stay cool guys and have a wonderful day :D*